# Testing simple webservice with Axis2 which takes Map as a parameter

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I have created a simple WebService which just prints the value of input.

```
public class MyWebService {
public MyVo basicService(MyVo vo) {
    System.out.println(vo.getName());
    System.out.println(vo.getParams());
    return vo;
}
}
```

And MyVo is like this :

```
public class MyVo {
private String name;
private HashMap<String, Serializable> params;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public HashMap<String, Serializable> getParams() {
    return params;
}
public void setParams(HashMap<String, Serializable> params) {
    this.params = params;
}
 }
```

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Helios Service Release 1 and Generating the webservice like :

New wizard , webservice, Selecting the server runtime (tomcat 6) and webruntime as Axis2. 
And clicking finish.

It generates the project with name TestClient. 
And inside that 2 classes : MyWebServiceCallbackHandler and MyWebServiceStub.

Once WebService is generated its also opening one JSP (WebService explorer) .
In that I can see the WebService and clicking on basicwebservice it shows UI where I can input my data.

But its not showing if I can add key/value for map. :(

I am not sure how to test this? Can I test this code using code?

I have attached the screen shot also.

I am new to WebService.
Any help on this will be very useful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you generating the web service, or the client (stub)?  Are you testing the web service, or the client?  What does your wsdl file look like?  Did you read the manual?

Comment: Well I am generating the clients and I want to just print the values. But how to pass or in the stub where to put the data to pass it to webservice? Through UI Jsp provided by eclipse its just passing the String type for map its printing null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to test your webservices.